# Concatenate two WAV files an then merge a third WAV file in SOX

Tags: linux, terminal

I have 3 wav files: 1.wav , 2.wav and noise.wav. 
I want to concatenate 1.wav and 2.wav in output.wav an then output.wav merge with noise.wav with a single SOX command. I know how to do this in 2 step. Is there a method to do in one step?

this is how i do it:

```
sox 1.wav 2.wav output.wav
sox -m output.wav noise.wav output2.wav
```

Answer (score 5):

After hours and hours of trying finaly i find a way to do this:

this is the anwser:

```
sox -m "|sox 1.wav 2.wav -p" noise.wav output.wav
```

where 1.wav, 2.wav and noise.wav are file localy stored and output.wav is the output generated by SOX.

I hope this save others time. I serch over the internet for this answer for days and no luck.

Comment: thanks, this helped alot :) Accept your own answer so people will know this is a resolved question :)